# Get all properties of an implemented interface

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I have the following setup:

```
public interface IInput
{
}

public class SomeInput : IInput
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Requester { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to write a function that can take anything that implements IInput and use reflection to give me the properties :

```
public Display(IInput input)
{
    foreach (var property in input.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" {property.Name}: {property.GetValue(input)}");
    }
}
```

Where

```
var test = new SomeInput(){Id=1,Requester="test"};
Display(test);
```

shows

```
Id: 1
Requester: test
```

Comment: Okay, so you seem to have given the code you wanted... so what's the question?

Comment: What he said. But do you just want the values for the object's IInput properties, or of all of its properties?

Comment: Wait, this will work? I figured reflection would only show me the interface's properties (IInput)  not the implemented properties (SomeInput)

Comment: `.GetType()` will give you the actual concrete type of the passed in object.

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper you showed it worked in your "shows" section already.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yeah that  was a want not an output, can see how that could of been confusing. I am all set now. I just coded it up in .net fiddle to see and I misunderstood what it would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `typeof()` you get the type of the variable. But if you use `GetType()` you get the actual runtime type, from which you can reflect all implemented properties.

```
void DumpProperties(IInput o)
{
    var t = o.GetType();
    var props = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Name: {0} Value: {1}",
            prop.Name,
            prop.GetValue(o).ToString()
        );
    }
}
```